# Why does URL redirect permission work in Chrome Manifest v2 but not v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to redirect a URL using the Chrome declarativeWebRequest API but it does not work.

The match pattern in the "permissions" key worked with Manifest V2 but it's now throwing a `Permission '*://www.youtube.com/*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed` error in V3.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Redirect Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "*://www.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://www.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

rules.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "redirect",
            "redirect": {"url": "https://www.google.com"}
        },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "*://www.youtube.com/*",
            "resourceTypes": [
                "main_frame"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I'm using Chrome 88.0.4324.104

Comment: `permissions` in ManifestV3 can only contain API permissions, not sites.

Comment: @wOxxOm Interesting. The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) has an example with a site in the permissions. Removing this url element doesn't redirect the site either.

Comment: Another problem is that `urlFilter` syntax is wrong AFAICT, see the documentation, it should be something like `||www.youtube.com/`. Also note that the documentation (and the extensions platform as a whole) is in extremely bad shape due to the lack of care or incompetence of Chromium team for the last 5+ years.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the help and info about the documentation! It seems that I needed to remove the url in the permissions, but the strange thing is that it still doesn't work for youtube.com--but it did work for other sites. I guess I'll create another question about that.

Comment: Ah, you need both sites in `host_permissions` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manifest documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#manifest) for declarative net requests at the time of posting isn't exactly accurate.

This is the
**Permissions key in manifest.json** from the documentation:

```
"permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "*://example.com/*"
  ],
```

However, the site should be specified in just `host_permissions` instead:

```
"host_permissions": [
    "*://example.com/*"
  ],
```

It should be noted that this explicit declaration is only necessary if `action.redirect` is specified like in this example:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 3,
        "action": {
            "type": "redirect",
            "redirect": {
                "regexSubstitution": "www.youtube.com/embed/"
            }
        },
        "condition": {
            "regexFilter": "(www\\.youtube\\.com\/watch\\?v=)",
            "resourceTypes": [
                "main_frame"
            ]
        }
}
```